# Как протянуть данные об идентификации маркера через кластеризацию?

Tags: android, google-maps-api, google-maps

Кластеризация маркеров завела меня в тупик.

Есть объект, данные которого я использую для отображения маркера на карте. Он хранится в базе данных.

Задача: при перетаскивании маркера на карте обновлять данные о его положении в БД.

До Кластеризации:
Маркеры я создавал вручную и каждому мог дать тег или id (соответствующий id объекта в БД). До и после перетаскивания, срабатывают методы onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) и onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker), из которых у объекта Marker я мог спокойно извлечь тег, найти объект в БД и обновить.

После кластеризации:
Маркеры вручную я больше не создаю! Теперь я создаю и передаю элементы в ClusterManager. Все что я теперь имею для заполнение маркера данными это объект MarkerOption в котором НЕТ возможности задать тег или id для маркера.
Соответственно теперь у меня нет данных чтобы идентифицировать маркер.

```
@Override
protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
    markerOptions.icon(BitmapUntils.getBitmapFromByteArray(item.getImage()));
    markerOptions.title(item.getTitle());
    markerOptions.draggable(true);
    super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
}
```

Можно бы было находить объект в базе по позиции но метод onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) возвращает маркер с уже измененной позиций потому маркер подпрыгивает после удержания(чтоб нам его было видно за пальцем).